# Tiny Core Linux 12, does not work with Xorg and br-abnt2 keyboard

Tags: xorg, tinycore

I installed Tiny Core 12, on an intel pc, 810i card. (40 hd, 733 mhz, 521 Ram), it runs very well.

I could not install the latest version because the driver package for the video 810 was not available. I uninstalled the vesa and installed Xorg 7.7, Driver and Kmap, because I need Kmap `br-abnt2`. I did all the procedures I found for the keyboard to work but only works in the terminal; the GUI does not work.

- In `Onbot.ist` is listed:

  ```
   Intel.810 Graphics-5.7.3 Xorg-7.7 Xrand Kmaps
  ```
- In `Quiet`, this:

  ```
  Kmap=qwerty/br-abnt2
  ```
- In `Bootsinc.sh`, this:

  ```shell
  Loadkmap < usr/share/kmap/qwerty/br-abnt2.kmap In tce/.xsession this [ -e /usr/local/bin/setxkbmap ] && setxkbmap -layout "br-abnt2" -variant "nodeadkeys"
  ```

Even so it starts but with the US keyboard, only in the terminal I have the `br-abnt2`.

Which part do I need to program to work in the GUI? I think it should be made some line in the Xorg code that should be edited since in the terminal it works normally. (translated from Portuguese-Br to English by deep.com)